# Visual Studio 2015 stops working when publishing an Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-webjobs

I am getting the following error entry on Event Viewer when publishing webjobs to Azure from Visual Studio 2015. The webjob gets published though but I have to reopen the solution because of the error:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source Application cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Error Handler Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended.
>   (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed,
>   see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended.
>   (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading
>   from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean
>   haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult) 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.EndRead()    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, Message& message)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext) \r\n    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, Message& message)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, RequestContext& requestContext)
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

Comment: Reinstall reinstall reinstall.

Comment: According to your description, we couldn't find the reason caused this. Have you installed the azure SDK for the visual studio? If you installed, which version? I suggest you could try to update the azure SDK to the newest version and test again.

Comment: Thank you I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Yes updating the SDK was the solutionm thanks @BrandoZhang . If you'd like to post your comment I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to make sure you have installed the newest azure SDK for the visual studio.

You could follow this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) to download the SDK and install it or could using [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to update the SDK.